# iOS 9.2 crash with [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, app-transport-security, ios9.2

When I run the following code on iOS 8.4 and 9.2 I get an NSData object `jsonData` that is 808 bytes:

```
NSData *jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

However if I then feed this NSData object into CJSONDeserializer I get a crash with iOS 9.2 but I get an NSDictionary with iOS 8.4. e.g.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:nil];
```

Note: at the line of the crash the NSData object seems to change - e.g. here:

```
- (id)deserializeAsDictionary:(NSData *)inData error:(NSError **)outError
{
if ([self _setData:inData error:outError] == NO)
```

`inData` is 808 bytes in iOS 8.4 but looks like the following in iOS 9.2:

[image: NSData]

which, because of the odd address, I assume means the object isn't correct (overwritten perhaps?).

I'm trying to figure out the problem without the overhead of App Transport Security so I have NSAppTransportSecurity set as follows:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I have also updated CJSONDeserializer to the latest version.

Any other suggestions what the problem might be.

Comment: What is the cause, crash log says ? I believe the result is not in valid json format.

Answer (score 1):

Try feeding an error object

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
```